# JQUERY Post & Php Session

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get or post an html dropdown box selected value using jquery `$.post` or `$.get` function into a PHP `$_SESSION` variable using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bid").change(function(){
            var bid=$("#bid").val();
        $.get('pget.php',{bid: bid}); }); })
</script>
```

After jquery sending 'bid' value into 'pget.php' thinking of getting the 'bid' value passed into the Php `$_SESSION` variable, no value is passed into the Php `$_SESSION` variable and this the code inside pget.php file

```
if(isset($_GET['bid'])){
$_SESSION['banchor']=$_GET['bid'];  }
```

Please, can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: Besides you needing both the `<?php` and `?>` in the second script. It seems that pget.php is giving some errors, I'd recommend logging them to a file and check them

Comment: What's up with the break tag lodged into the PHP?

Comment: Your JS syntax looks broken (missing brackets etc.) I guess just copy&paste error?

Comment: @Fred -ii- : man thanx, i just realised session_start() was not loaded

Comment: @ Francisco, @ RUJordan yh i do have the <?php ?> tags in the second script

Comment: It should be `<?php if(isset($_GET['bid'])){
$_SESSION['banchor']=$_GET['bid'];  } ?> <br />` don't put the `<br />` inside PHP unless you concatenate it.

Comment: @ Fred -ii-: hmm, it seems after adding the session_start(); it still seems that the bid value is not put into the $_SESSION variable and i dont why is behaving so...any suggestion?

Comment: I absolutely stink at jQuery.

Comment: @Felk, yh some copy and paste eliminated those closing tags and i have fix them, can anybody still help?

Comment: @ All contributors, the bug is fixed with your supports, thanx

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. Cheers +1 for self-fix.